# Robot framework: How to get the URL to a variable?

Tags: variables, url, robotframework

I need to get the url of my current window to a variable. I am trying:

${attribute} =  Execute Javascript  window.location.href;

It returns only "None" when I log and try to see the value. 
(15:56:00.536 INFO ${attribute} = None )

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using SeleniumLibrary (or the older Selenium2Library), you can use the [Get Location](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Location) keyword:

```
${href}=    Get Location
```

Comment: This has been updated to use SeleniumLibrary http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Location

Comment: @dday: thanks for the comment. I've updated the answer to reflect the new name and url.